# EMC + erase LUNS from EMC storage by tool/script

Tags: linux, storage, emc

the following link explain how to destroy LUNS / RAID configuration manual VIA Navisphere GUI

```
        http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/04/emc-delete-lun-raid-group/
```

my question - I want to find script/tool that run on Linux/Solaris and script/tool can remove LUNS and RAID group from EMC in place to remove the LUNES VIA Navisphere GUI ( manual removing )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [navicli](http://www.emc.com/collateral/software/white-papers/h6431-clariion-navisphere-cli-history-wp.pdf).

Comment: I need script that erase LUN storage not navi cli commands

Comment: You can use navicli to unpresent and delete volumes. Do you need to delete the data on them first?